diagonal argument in latex
How can I draw the following figure in latex please? 

On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

For comparison, here is an effort in Metapost, with an entertaining use of loops.

Replacing the extremities with dots is left as an exercise...
You need to compile this source with lualatex:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  picture t[]; numeric n; n = 0;
  for k=1 upto 7 :
    numeric a, b, s; 
    if odd k:
      a = k; b = 1; s = -1;
    else:
      a = 1; b = k; s = 1;
    fi
    for i = a step s until b:
      t[incr n] = thelabel("$\langle " & decimal (k+1-i) & "," & decimal i & "\rangle$", 
                           (i, i - k) yscaled 32 xscaled 42);
    endfor
  endfor

  for i = 1 upto n:
    draw t[i];
  endfor
  ahangle := 30;
  bboxmargin := 5;
  for i = 1 upto n - 1:
    drawarrow center bbox t[i] -- center bbox t[i+1]
      cutbefore bbox t[i] cutafter bbox t[i+1];
  endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}


With just a bit of visual formatting:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\settowidth{\dimen0}{$(0.0)$}
\newcommand{\fcdot}{\makebox[\dimen0]{$\mathstrut\cdot$}}
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=1.5em]
(1,1) \arrow[d]  & (1,2) \arrow[r]  & (1,3) \arrow[dl] & (1,4) \arrow[r] 
  & \fcdot \arrow[dl] &[-2.3em] \cdot &[-1.5em] \cdot \\
(2,1) \arrow[ur] & (2,2) \arrow[dl] & (2,3) \arrow[ur] & (2,4) \arrow[dl]
  & \fcdot & \cdot & \cdot\\
(3,1) \arrow[d]  & (3,2) \arrow[ur] & (3,3) \arrow[dl] & (3,4) \arrow[ur]
  & \fcdot \arrow[dl] & \cdot & \cdot\\
(4,1) \arrow[ur] & (4,2) \arrow[dl] & (4,3) \arrow[ur] & (4,4) \arrow[dl]
  & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\fcdot            & \fcdot \arrow[ur] & \fcdot            & \cdot           
  & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\[-1.7em]
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\[-1.5em]  
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}


